# GeoServer Auth with empty password method

Tags: geoserver, authentication, jdbc

I'm trying to implement auth with empty password (cf.: [GeoServer Documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.25.x/en/user/security/passwd.html#empty)) with users imported from an external postgres DB (with a JDBC user group service).

The point is that the JDBC connection is valid, I can see users and roles imported from my DB. Because I've got an external auth system with an external backend, I'd like to allow users to log in with an empty password. But when I try to log in through the GeoServer GUI with one of those user, it told me Invalid username/password combination.

I'm certainly missing something but I need more explainations that I found in the docs.

---

EDIT

Bellow, the logs while trying to log in:
(it's really because when I configure my user group service, the tst connection is working great but, in the logs, when I try to normally connect without pass, It seems to fail...

```
geoserver  | 11:04:03 WARN   [geoserver.security] - JDBC connect error

geoserver  | org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: JDBC connect error

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.jdbc.JDBCConnectAuthProvider.authenticate(JDBCConnectAuthProvider.java:87)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(GeoServerAuthenticationProvider.java:54)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager$1.authenticate(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:314)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:100)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)

geoserver  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)

geoserver  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

geoserver  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

geoserver  | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but the password is an empty string.

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.lambda$doAuthentication$4(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:844)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.AuthenticationPluginManager.withPassword(AuthenticationPluginManager.java:81)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:835)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)

geoserver  |    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)

geoserver  |    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)

geoserver  |    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)

geoserver  |    at org.geoserver.security.jdbc.JDBCConnectAuthProvider.authenticate(JDBCConnectAuthProvider.java:82)

geoserver  |    ... 56 more

geoserver  | 11:04:03 WARN   [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user test_user from 172.25.0.1
```

I guess that the most interresting line is this one but I don't understand what I should do:

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but the password is an empty string.`

Comment: can you include the log file entry for the attempt? and check that users can log into Postgresql from the GeoServer machine

Comment: @IanTurton I updated my post with logs and a little explanation of what I do when I get it.
It's strange because I'm able to test successfully the connection and to add data with the PG administrator db...
Another point to notice is that I'm using docker (the official image here: https://github.com/geoserver/docker/tree/master )

Comment: @IanTurton is it needed, in the case of a JDBC user group connexion, to have each users  in a table "users" AND to have them in the pg_roles table ?

Comment: You still need to provide a password, EMPTY just means that GeoServer doesn't store a copy.

Comment: oh ... alright ! The fact is that I have a table my_users used by my backend where I store passwords and a lot of other stuff. So I need to have a table "my_users", a table "users" (used by Geoserver with an empty col of password) and the same users stored in the pg_role table (but with the same passwords policy than the one used by the backend to log into the geoserver gui). Is it exact ?

Comment: are you trying to use [JDBC Role Service](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/usergrouprole/roleservices.html#jdbc-role-service) [JDBC User Service](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/usergrouprole/usergroupservices.html#security-rolesystem-usergroupjdbc) or [JDBC Authentication provider](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/auth.html#jdbc-provider) as they all do different things

Comment: I'm using all of them. The two first ones to use the users created by my backend inside geoserver and manage the groups and roles used in geoserver through my backend. And the last one to allow my users to connect to the geoserver GUI. Why ?

Comment: because they all do different things, please clarify your question as to which one you are having issues with and exactly how you have configured it

Comment: Alright, let's take only one single and specific issue about the auth provider. (to be pragmatic, I removed the role and user services)
In my DB, I have two users (in the pg_roles table, not in a project-specific table) : admin (superuser) and joe (standard user).
I removed the geoserver admin user provided with the default user-group service to be sure the issue is related to my pg user admin.
When I log with joe: success, with admin: success too but in the logs I have:
JDBC connect error ... password authentication failed for user "admin"...